# Как заполнить datagridcomboboxcolumn

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет. Есть некая ViewModel которая биндится к DataGrid.

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Person> People {get; set}
}

 class Person
 {
      public string Name {get; set;}

      public List<Car> Cars {get; set;}
  }

  class Car
  {
      public string Name {get; set;}
  }
```

Далее я пытаюсь эту модель прибандить к dataGrid. Поле типа DataGridTextColumn бандится без проблем. Но вот поле DataGridComboBoxColumn  никак не заполняется данными. Как его привязать?

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPerson" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding People }" >

   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" 
                       Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"> 
   </DataGridTextColumn>

   <!-- Это поле НЕ бандится.  В нем я хочу чтобы отображался 
         список машин человека  -->    
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Машины" 
                           Binding="{Binding Path=Cars}"  
                           DisplayMemberPath="Name">
   </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: 1) А зачем вам `DisplayMemberPath="Name"`? 2) В VM должны быть dependency property (ну или быть реализовано `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Comment: Делал по аналогии ComboBox. Там такая привязка работает.

Comment: Т.е. чего я хочу добиться. Чтобы в каждой строке грида отображался конкретный пользователь, а в поле DataGridComboBoxColumn  этого грида отображался список машин данного пользователя.

Answer (score 5):

Из [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To populate the drop-down list, first set the ItemsSource property for the ComboBox by using one of the following options:
>
> - A static resource. For more information, see [StaticResource Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - An `x:Static` code entity. For more information, see [x:Static Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
> - An inline collection of [`ComboBoxItem`](msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx) types.

Поскольку для вас ни один из трёх вариантов не подходит, применить `DataGridComboBoxColumn` не получится.

Попробуйте так:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Машины">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но хотелось все-таки сделать привязку к DataGridTemplateColumn. Как-то она все-таки делается, но в найденных мной примерах не разобрался.

Comment: @sp7: Я привёл ссылку на документацию, которая говорит, что использовать `DataGridComboBoxColumn` в вашем случае не стоит. Если уж разработчик так говорит, лучше послушаться: кто знает, какие ещё проблемы возникнут? Официальная документация всяко заруливает примеры из гугла.

Comment: В общем решил оставить в покое DataGridTemplateColumn и оформить пользовательский интерфейс немного по другому.